# Legenda + string

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou gerando um gráfico usando ggplot2 e gostaria de explicitar na legenda uma variável denominada Sbarra. No entanto, eu quero que a "barra" fique "em cima" da letra S. Alguém pode me auxiliar? Grato.

Exemplo:

```
#################################################
df= 
Subgrupos Legenda value 
1 LM 7.215 
2 S  9.517 
3 LSC 14.175 
5 LIC 0.255
6 LM 7.215 
7 LSC 14.175 
8 LIC 0.255
9 S 10.660 
10 LM 7.215 
11 S 8.079 
12 LSC 14.175 
13 LM 7.215
14 LIC 0.255
15 S 11.826

Fig1 <- ggplot(df, aes(Subgrupos, value, group = Legenda)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Legenda, color = Legenda, size = Legenda))+ 
  geom_point(data = df[(df$value) & df$Legenda == "S",],
             aes(group = Legenda), size = 4) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c('solid','dashed', 'dashed','dashed'))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000","#800080","#006400","#0000FF"))+
  scale_size_manual(values=c(1, 1.5,1.5,1.5)) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) + 
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = 'black', angle = 45, size = 13, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5),
    legend.position = 'bottom', 
    legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
    axis.title = element_text(face='bold')
  ) + 
  labs(x='Subgrupos', y='Valores')

#################################################
```

O meu objetivo é que na legenda apareça `"S barra"` (com a barra grafada sobre a letra S) e não apenas `"S"`.
Att.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para por a barra em cima do `"S"`, usa-se a função `expression` com `bar()`, veja `help(plotmath")`.

Como tem 3 *aesthetics*, `linetype`, `color` e `size`, tem que repetir o `expression`, uma vez para cada *aes*.

Além disso, retirei o `df$value` de `geom_point`, não estava lá a fazer nada.

```
library(ggplot2)

Fig1 <- ggplot(df, aes(Subgrupos, value, group = Legenda)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Legenda, color = Legenda, size = Legenda))+ 
  geom_point(data = df[df$Legenda == "S",],
             aes(group = Legenda), size = 4) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c('solid','dashed', 'dashed','dashed'))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000","#800080","#006400","#0000FF"))+
  scale_size_manual(values=c(1, 1.5,1.5,1.5)) + 
  labs(
    x = 'Subgrupos', y = 'Valores',
    linetype = expression(bar("S")),
    color = expression(bar("S")),
    size = expression(bar("S"))
  ) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) + 
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", angle = 45, size = 13, 
                               hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5),
    legend.position = 'bottom', 
    legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
    axis.title = element_text(face='bold')
  )

Fig1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Excelente!! Muitíssimo obrigado pela valiosa ajuda!!!

Comment: O que fazer quando [alguém responde](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) às suas perguntas.